# Python: iteration problems

Tags: python, text, iteration

I am performing text processing on a text file and have been trying to iterate into a for loop.

```
fields = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
with open('file path', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # while i is smaller than the number of fields (=5)
        while i <= len(fields)-1:
            currentfield = fields[i]
            # if the first character of the line matches currentfield
            # (that being a number)
            if line[0] == currentfield:
                print(line[4:])  # print the value in the "third column"
            i += 1
```

The text file "f" has something like this (the numbers between the dashes indicate years, and each year has its own "entry"):

```
-------------2000--------------
1        17824
2        20131125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    DLC
4    b    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 750
-------------2001--------------
1        3224
2        20w125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
5    a    WA 120
-------------2002--------------
1        6563453
2        2013341524626245.9
3        484914s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 345
```

There is actually no columns in the text file, but the space between the fields numbers (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and the values after (i.e. 17824) have two tab-spaces. I just didn't know how to call the 17824.

What I am trying to do is iterate over all the fields for each entry/year, but the output only gives me the values for the first field, 1.Thus I get as the following as the output:

```
17824    
3224     
6563453
```

Instead of iterating over all the fields, it only iterates over the first one. How can I fix my code such that the output is created into a table-like form where it iterates over the fields 2, 3, 4, and 5 as well? Like this:

```
17824    20131125192004.9    690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng  ...and so on
3224     20w125192004.9      690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng  ...and so on
6563453  2013341524626245.9  484914s1969    dcu           000 0 eng  ...and so on
```

Edit: I understand I wasn't being as clear, so I added some parts.

Comment: I'm assuming you missed a `i=0` initialisation?

Comment: @alexmcf Just edited, it was in my code. Thanks for the catch though!

Comment: I am not still sure what you are trying to do . Generally I'd recommend, truncating multiple occurences of whitespace characters with a single space and split by that and strip to remove trailing and leading spaces. so something like `re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line).strip() ` would work. But as I said what you want is stil not clear.

Comment: After your edit, the problem is that the `i=0` is in the wrong place. Instead of counting from 0 to 4 each time, you're counting from 0 to 4 the first time, then from 5 to 4 every time after that. You need to reset `i=0` inside the outer loop. Or, better, don't try to use a `while` loop to do a `for` loop's job. If you just want to iterate the numbers 0 to 4, use `for i in range(5):`. Or, even better, if the only reason you want those numbers is as indices into `fields`, just do `for field in fields:`.

Comment: @abarnert: I tried `for field in fields:` but it just went through the for index of `fields`, which is 1. It didn't go through 2, 3, 4, and 5. Do you know why? 
I put:
    with open('file path', 'r') as f:
        for field in fields:
            for line in f:
                if line[0:3]==field:
                    print line[4:]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @user112947: Why did you move the `for field in fields:` outside the `for line in f:`, instead of leaving it inside like your `while` loop? If you move it outside, then it going to read the entire file starting at the beginning for the first field, then read the entire file starting at the end (in other words, nothing) for the second field, etc. If you leave it inside, it's going to go through all of the fields for each line, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will help you:

```
for line in f:
    print '\nline[0] is %s' % line[0]
    for currentfield in fields: # loop through all fields
        # convert currentfield to string
        if line[0] == str(currentfield): #if the first character of the line matches currentfield (that being a number)
            print 'Printing field %d' % current field # debugging
            print line[4:] #print the value in the "third column"
```

this gave me:

```
u'''line[0] is -

line[0] is 1
Printing field 1
    17824

line[0] is 2
Printing field 2
    20131125192004.9

line[0] is 3
Printing field 3
    690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
a      75601809 

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
a   DLC

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
b   eng

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
c   DLC

line[0] is 5
Printing field 5
a   WA 750

line[0] is -

line[0] is 1
Printing field 1
    3224

line[0] is 2
Printing field 2
    20w125192004.9

line[0] is 3
Printing field 3
    690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng

line[0] is 5
Printing field 5
a   WA 120

line[0] is -

line[0] is 1
Printing field 1
    6563453

line[0] is 2
Printing field 2
    2013341524626245.9

line[0] is 3
Printing field 3
    484914s1969    dcu           000 0 eng

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
a      75601809 

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
a   eng

line[0] is 4
Printing field 4
c   DLC

line[0] is 5
Printing field 5
a   WA 345'''
```

by the way changing `line[:4]` to `line[:8]` will give the third column from the data you pasted above.

You can then use regex to remove anything following a space after the third column data.

---

**Edit for your changed Q**

Here I join up each line and remove all spaces leaving the columns as a list with `l = [el for el in ''.join(line) if el != '']`. you can then index the column by referring to it directly e.g. for column 4: `l[4]`

```
for line in f:
    l = [el for el in ''.join(line) if el != '']
    print '\nline[0] is %s' % line[0]
    for currentfield in fields: # loop through all fields
        # convert currentfield to string
        if l[0] == str(currentfield): #if the first character of the line matches currentfield (that being a number)
            print 'Printing field %d' % current field # debugging
            print l[currentfield] #print the value in the "third column"
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Python keeps giving me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: by the way I used `f = """[your pasted file data]""".split('\n')` to recreate your file read. Perhaps try with that